# SqlDataAdapter Count Row returned

Tags: c#

I have `SqlDataAdapter` query in C# windows application. I need to know the number of return rows before I fill it in the `DataGridView` due to when the number is 1 million rows the fill method takes 9 seconds.

I need a way doesn't need to fill all data in DataTable and get count then I use paging principle to display the data like this

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 query = new Classes.order().GetAllBills();

 query.Fill(dt);
 DateTime date1 = System.DateTime.Now;
 MaxCount = dt.Rows.Count;

 int maxPag = (MaxCount / 25)+1;
 lblMaxCount.Text = MaxCount.ToString() ;

 lblNumOfPagFromAll.Text = (CounterPaging / 25) + "/" + maxPag;
 dt = new DataTable();
 query.Fill(CounterPaging,maxRecord,dt);

 dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Why don't you just always page results?

Comment: because I need to now all returned records to display the max number of pages and the number of current  page

Comment: The idea about paging is that the user can start using the data, you need to ask the question what the added value to end user is if he knows there are 1milj or 1000002 records. If it is important, Let the task of the count run in background and show when you get answer. Second option in track on db all inserts, deletes to have it always available.

Comment: @user3406790 Please edit your question to include the full source code of the `Classes` class and the class returned by `Classes.order()`. Getting the number of rows is a simple `SELECT COUNT(*)` statement.

Comment: You should use [Virtual Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/virtual-mode-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control) in DataGridView.

Comment: special thanks for helping
it works count(*) it took 79 milliseconds to get 100K records and for me its great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `SqlDataAdapter` *cannot return the number of rows* before all rows have been fetched. This is simply because the underlying database driver will not provide this information. So you have to count the rows while or after fetching them.

#### SELECT COUNT(*)

Alternatively you need to **query the database for the number of results** as Progman suggested. But this has some *drawbacks*.

- First of all the database need to fetch the data twice. While caching might make the second access fast, this also might *not* happen, e.g. if the number of rows is very large and flushes the cache.
- Secondly this is a race condition. The data might change after `SELECT COUNT(*)` returning an entirely different number of rows by the `SqlDataAdapter`.

#### SELECT TOP

Another solution is to **let the database handle the paging**. In T-SQL `SELECT TOP n ...` will do the job.

The drawback is that you cannot retrieve the total number of pages this way.
But it is easy to check whether there is further data. Simply select one row more than the page size. If you get n+1 rows there is another page.

### `DataTable` = poor performance

One last note: *If performance counts get rid of the data tables and adaptors.* They are not intended to be used for significantly more data than it fits on the screen.
Especially if you have many value types like `int` or `DateTime` the effect is significant because of the excessive auto boxing.

I refactored a C# application this way some time ago and the speed increased by almost two orders of magnitude.
I did another change simultaneously: I deduplicated identical strings from different rows in the result set. This also reduced the memory footprint by almost one order of magnitude because some values got repeated quite often.

It was that fast that I ended up by loading all data into a session cache and do the paging from this cache. Even several millions of rows took only in the order of one second.

Comment: special thanks @Marcel for helping
it works count(*).
 it took 79 milliseconds to get 100K records and for me its great